# Python how can you check for consecutive letters in a user input?

Tags: python

How can you check a user input in python for every time a set of 3 consecutive characters appears (according to a qwerty keyboard). It should also be case insensitive.

E.g: `asDFg` should have three sets (`asD`, `sDF`, and `DFg`), and 1 point should be subtracted from a score for each set.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're looking for consecutive characters, shouldn't `sDF` be included as well? And are you saying you want to keep a running total for every set of three consecutive QWERTY characters (so whenever you see `asD` you change it's score)?

Comment: @jpyams Yes sDF should be included, and there sould be a running total, so asDFg should return 3. Sorry for the rushed question

Comment: If you have some code you have already written as an attempt at this, include that in your question. [Showing your work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) shows that you've put some effort into your problem and helps others answer your question better

Comment: @jpyams I would have, but I genuinely don't even know where to begin with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use three strings a b and c representing each row in qwerty keyboard and check for substrings while converting to lowercase

```
a="qwertyuiop"
b="asdfghjkl"
c="zxcvbnm"
str=raw_input()
score=0
for i in range(0,len(str)-2):
    t=str[i:i+3]
    if t.lower() in a or t.lower() in b or t.lower() in c :
        score+=1
    else:
        score-=1
print score
```

input

```
asDFg
```

output

```
3
```

Comment: You can make creating the substring a bit neater by using string splicing: `t = str[i:i+3]`